# Sometime Client have resp 400 - Bad Request from Server

Tags: java, xml, soap, request, response

I am handling server SOAP client, sometime I have reviece response :

```
400 - Bad Request
```

=> I set in code:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
```

I have log below:

```
---[HTTP request - https://example.com:4443/SMN_LoanAddlInfo]---
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Authorization: Basic ZXNiX3VhdF9zbWFydG5ldF91c2VyOnB3c1VBVEAxMlNNXSATg==
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://sub.example.com/SMN_LoanAddlInfo/GetLoanAccountInfo"
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e
<?xml version="1.0" ?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:smn="http://sub.domain.com/SMN_LoanAddlInfo/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><smn:GetLoanAccountInfo><SysRequest xmlns=""><TransID>16506816825500863</TransID><RequestorID>ABC</RequestorID><DateTime>2020-05-26T11:54:41.658+07:00</DateTime></SysRequest><AccountNumber xmlns="">20200303-5907580</AccountNumber></smn:GetLoanAccountInfo></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

case ERROR in log not print response msg, but catch trace (System.out.println("exception_stack_trace_processRequest=" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));)
```

I have this error message :

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 400: Bad Request
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:310)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:259)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
```

I have 20% response 400 in total request send in prod.

I don't understand, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: structure network SOAP client have use proxy

Comment: it can be because of lots of reasons, I recommend you to log some of the requests, to make sure what exactly is wrong, most likely requests don't pass validation

Comment: @GiorgosDev thanks for reply, but i have checked many req message it simple with format as number. please view my update with msg req.

Comment: @GiorgosDev i have 7-8 req SUCCESS then have 1 req 400 - Bad Request in multil day. I don't understand what's happend.

Comment: The log you provide is on the client side.  Do you have a log from the server?

Comment: @GiorgosDev I have connecting with partner's server, but partner reply not have req in elesticsearch. OMG :(

Comment: I closed this question. Thanks.